# React Native (Android) detect sound exists on remote video url

Tags: android, react-native, android-mediaplayer

I want to create a native android module to detect whether audio tracks exist on a video. Right now I'm using MediaPlayer, but onPrepared isn't being called. Am I missing something? The native module bundles correctly as well. My log says `MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://storage.googleapis.com/SPECIAL_FILE.mp4`

```java
public class RNSoundDetectionModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public RNSoundDetectionModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }
  @ReactMethod
  public void doesLocalVideoHaveAudioTrack(String path, Callback cb) {
    boolean audioTrack =false;

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(path);
    String hasAudioStr = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO);
    if(hasAudioStr!=null && hasAudioStr.equals("yes")){
     audioTrack=true; }
    else{
    audioTrack=false; }
    try {
      cb.invoke(audioTrack, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      cb.invoke(e.toString(), null);
    }
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void getRemoteAudioTracks(String path, final Callback cb) {
    try {
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
      mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){

      @Override
          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
              cb.invoke(mp.getTrackInfo(), null);
          }
      });
      mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      cb.invoke(e.toString(), null);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "RNSoundDetection";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - see my library here: https://github.com/evanjmg/react-native-sound-detection